# Passing dates as varchar to a Stored Procedure in SQL Server

Tags: java, sql-server, spring, hibernate, callable-statement

I have a Stored Procedure that accepts parameters like so :

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [DataExtract].[USP_GET_ACTIVATIONS]
(
  @UNITID INT = NULL,
  @STARTDATE VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
  @ENDDATE VARCHAR(30) = NULL,
  @TEST BIT = 0
)
AS
BEGIN
......
```

When I execute this from the SQL Server console, it returns the data I expect.

```
EXEC    [DataExtract].[USP_GET_ACTIVATIONS]
        @UNITID = 1,
        @STARTDATE = N'2020-06-29',
        @ENDDATE = N'2020-07-08',
        @TEST = 1
GO
```

I am trying to invoke this procedure using this callable statement

```
final SQLServerConnection connection = (SQLServerConnection) ds.getConnection();
SQLServerCallableStatement callableStatement = (SQLServerCallableStatement) connection.prepareCall("{call [DataExtract].[USP_GET_ACTIVATIONS](?, ?, ?, ?)}");
callableStatement.setInt(1, 1);
callableStatement.setString(2, "2020-06-29");
callableStatement.setString(3, "2020-07-08");
callableStatement.setBoolean(4, true);
final boolean execute = callableStatement.execute();
//execute is always false
```

The statement always returns the result as `false` (and the resultSet `null`). I'm guessing there's something wrong with the way I'm passing dates, but I can't figure out what.

How do I go about fixing this issue? (Changing the SP is not an option since there are many other components that depend on this)

Comment: Does your stored procedure only run a select (or run a select first), or does it first run an update or insert statement before running the select?

Comment: @allmhuran No, its just a select statement with some joins later on,

Comment: I'm certainly no java guy, but I believe you should be able to use`executeQuery` if your procedure does indeed only return a single result set. But even so, I suggest debugging with an additional line of code which calls `getMoreResults()`, just to make absolutely sure there isn't anything coming out prior to your result set.

Comment: Is it possible your date values need to be passed in with single ticks ( e.g., '2020-06-29' )?

Comment: @allmhuran the resultSet is empty. And there's only one select statement so getMoreResults() returns false

Comment: Are there other data modifying statements in the stored procedure before the select statement? You might have to start the proc off with `SET NOCOUNT ON` so that Java doesn't get confused by additional rowcounts without results.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning OMG I LOVE YOU! It was SET NOCOUNT ON. Can you post this as an answer ?